# How to turn off highlighting in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've tried looking over all the settings but can't find a way of turning off the highlighting of other uses of the variable under the caret. Hopefully this screenshot shows what I mean.

[image: screenshot]

Thanks,
Drew

Comment: You really want this off? It is quite a convenient feature imo.

Comment: Honestly, I just find it really distracting. Like from my screenshot above - the caret is on the second line in the "val" variable, but the highlighting makes all the other references stand out more. I'm not saying it's a bad feature, just not one for me.

Comment: The correct way to complete a question on SO is to upvote helpful answers and mark one as accepted - not to incorporate a (partial) *answer* into your question, nor to change the title to include "Solved".

Comment: Cheers for setting me straight Damien, thanks for that. I've removed my answer from the question and added it as proper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was because I had Productivity Power Tools installed as well, which duplicates this feature with a badly named option.

So to turn this off, you need to turn off the regular option (thanks to stijn):

[image]

But then ALSO turn off this second option:

[image]

Hopefully this'll help someone in the future!

Comment: Don.t do this. Put the answer *in your answer*.

Answer (score 2):

`Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Advanced->Highlight references to symbol under cursor`

Comment: Thanks stijn, but I'd already turned that off (I should have said that!). I've discovered it's because the Productivity Power Tools plugin sort of duplicates this behaviour, so there was another (badly named) setting that also needed turning off. I've updated my original question to give both answers now.

Comment: I believe the option you were referring to is "Show matches in the editor" under Productivity Power Tools --> General "Match margin options" section